# How to draw this and write this in set theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this set equation

$$([1,2]\times(2,5))\cap\left((\Bbb R\times[3,4])\cup\left(\left[\frac12,\frac32\right]\times\Bbb R\right)\right)$$

which is quite hard for me, I know that it's supposed to be a triangle but I really don't know how to draw it correct.

How could I write this in set theory interval notation and how does it look drawn?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: It is not a triangle, but some sort of horizontal T. Use distributivity of set operations.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following identity useful for sets $A,B,C$: $$A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$$

As mentioned in the comments, the set is not a rectangle, but a T on its side. It can be described as $\Big(\Big\lbrack1,\frac{3}{2}\Big\rbrack\times(2,5)\Big)\cup\Big(\Big\lbrack1,2\Big\rbrack\times\lbrack3,4\rbrack\Big)$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}\times[3,4]$ and $[\frac12,\frac32]\times\mathbb{R}$ are infinite rectangles\strips the former bounded in $y$, the later in $x$, so their union is an infinite cross ($\dagger$), "centered" at $[\frac12,\frac32]\times[3,4]$.
[image]

Intersection of the cross with the "clopen" rectangle
$[1,2]\times(2,5)$ 
[image]

will cut the infinite part of the plus as following, 
the top and bottom open boundaries are $(2,5)$ the right and left close boundaries $[1,2]$. The cross ($\dagger$) become a vertical bar with a spur at the right side ($\vdash$). The bar is a $[1,\frac32]\times[2,5]$, the spur is a $(\frac32,2)\times[3,4]$.

[image]